# Syntax error when creating an object in a p5js sketch

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to create a background scenery with objects cloud, mountain, tree, canyon etc. Everything is going well, except when I reached creating the cloud object. I have declared the `var cloud` for the cloud object and initialized the values of the coordinates of `cloud` in the setup function as `cloud = (pos_x: 200, pos_y: 70, diameter: 130);`. However, when I try to create the cloud object with the ellipse shape in the `draw()` function as mentioned below, it gives me 2 problems:

1. I do not get the autofill `cloud.pos_x` when I enter `cloud.` in the `ellipse();`
2. Error `*sketch.js:23 Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token ':'*` (dot on top of each other), after I run the code.

I hope I have given you enough details to understand the issue. Thank you.

```
var floorPos_y;

var gameChar_x;
var gameChar_y;

var treePos_x;
var treePos_y;

var canyon;
var collectable;

var mountain;

var cloud; 
var cloudPos_x: 
var cloudPos_y; 
var cloudDiameter; 



function setup()
{
    createCanvas(1024, 576);
    floorPos_y = 432; //NB. we are now using a variable for the floor position

    //NB. We are now using the built in variables height and width
    gameChar_x = width/2;
    gameChar_y = floorPos_y;

    treePos_x = width/2;
    treePos_y = height/2;
    
    cloud = (pos_x: 200, pos_y: 70, diameter: 130); 
}

function draw()
{
    background(100, 155, 255); //fill the sky blue

    noStroke();
    fill(34, 139, 34);
    rect(0, floorPos_y, height, width - floorPos_y); //draw some green ground
    triangle(height + 200, floorPos_y - 20, height + 50, floorPos_y - 20, height + 50, floorPos_y); 
    quad(height, floorPos_y + 20, height, floorPos_y - 20, height + 50, floorPos_y - 20, height + 50, floorPos_y); 
    rect(0, floorPos_y - 20, height, 20);
    quad(width - 200, floorPos_y - 20, width, floorPos_y - 20, width, floorPos_y, width - 100, floorPos_y); 
    
    
    //draw tree
    fill(139, 69, 19); 
    rect(treePos_x, treePos_y, 30, 150); 
    fill(34, 139, 34);
    ellipse(treePos_x + 15, treePos_y - 50, 150, 200); 
    ellipse(treePos_x + 15, treePos_y - 150, 120, 200); 
    
    //Canyon
    fill(244, 164, 96); 
    quad(height, floorPos_y + 20, height + 50, floorPos_y, height + 50, height - 50, height, height); 
    quad(width, floorPos_y, width - 100, floorPos_y, width - 100, height - 50, width, height); 
    quad(width - 100, floorPos_y, width - 200, floorPos_y - 20, width - 200,  floorPos_y + 20, width - 100, height - 50); 
    quad(height + 50, floorPos_y, height + 200, floorPos_y - 20, height + 200, floorPos_y + 30, height + 50, height - 50); 
    quad(width - 200, floorPos_y - 20, height + 200, floorPos_y - 10, height + 200, floorPos_y + 10, width - 200,  floorPos_y + 20); 
    fill(0, 255, 255); 
    triangle(height + 200, floorPos_y + 10, width - 200,  floorPos_y + 20, height + 200, floorPos_y + 30); 
    quad(height, height, height + 50, height - 50, width - 100, height - 50, width, height); 
    quad(height + 50, height - 50, height + 200, floorPos_y + 30, width - 200,  floorPos_y + 20, width - 100, height - 50); 
    
    //Mountain
    fill(244, 164, 96);
    triangle(0, height - 500, 100, floorPos_y - 20, 0, floorPos_y - 20); 
    quad(20, height - 400, 60, height - 450, 170, floorPos_y - 20, 100, floorPos_y - 20); 
    quad(50, height - 300, 120, height - 360, 220, floorPos_y - 20, 150, floorPos_y - 20); 
    quad(100, height - 250, 190, height - 300, 320, floorPos_y - 20, 200, floorPos_y - 20);
    fill(105, 105, 105); 
    triangle(0, height - 100, 400, floorPos_y - 20, 0, height); 
    
    //cloud
    fill(255, 255, 255); 
    ellipse(cloud.
    
    
    //collectable
    strokeWeight(3); 
    stroke(240, 248, 255); 
    fill(220, 20, 60); 
    quad(height - 200, height - 50, height - 170, height - 100, height - 80, height - 100, height - 70, height - 50); 
    noFill();
    strokeWeight(3); 
    stroke(255, 69, 0); 
    //curve(height - 200, height - 70, height - 200, height - 120, height - 180, height - 120, height - 180, height - 70); 
    curve(height - 200, height - 70, height - 200, height - 70, height - 200, height - 120, height - 180, height - 120);
    curve(height - 200, height - 70, height - 200, height - 120, height - 180, height - 120, height - 180, height - 70); 
    curve(height - 200, height - 120, height - 180, height - 120, height - 180, height - 70, height - 180, height - 70); 
    fill(255, 255, 0); 
    quad(height - 210, height - 40, height - 220, height - 70, height - 160, height - 70, height - 170, height - 40); 
    
    
    // draw the game character
    noStroke(); 
    fill(220, 220, 220); 
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 65, 25, 25); 
    fill(0, 0, 0); 
    rect(gameChar_x - 15, gameChar_y - 55, 30, 50); 
    stroke(0, 0, 0); 
    strokeWeight(03); 
    point(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 65); 
    strokeWeight(01); 
    stroke(255); 
    rect(gameChar_x - 20, gameChar_y - 55, 05, 25);   
    rect(gameChar_x + 15, gameChar_y - 55, 05, 25);
    noStroke(); 
    fill(255, 255, 255); 
    triangle(gameChar_x - 05, gameChar_y - 53, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 50, gameChar_x - 05, gameChar_y - 47); 
    triangle(gameChar_x + 05, gameChar_y - 53, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 50, gameChar_x + 05, gameChar_y - 47); 
    fill(119, 136, 153); 
    rect(gameChar_x - 12, gameChar_y - 10, 10, 15); 
    rect(gameChar_x + 02, gameChar_y - 10, 10, 15); 


}

function mousePressed()
{
    gameChar_x = mouseX;
    gameChar_y = mouseY; 
    

}
```

Comment: It is called a colon

Comment: `var cloudPos_x: ` note the colon here where you need a semicolon.  Also, `cloudPos_x` is different from `cloud.pos_x`.  Finally, `ellipse(cloud.` just stops.  There's no closing parenthesis, there's no values sent to the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error which tells you that you used some invalid character. Here it is because you don't create an object with `(...)` but with `{...}`.

Replacing

```
cloud = (pos_x: 200, pos_y: 70, diameter: 130);
```

with

```
cloud = {pos_x: 200, pos_y: 70, diameter: 130};
```

Should solve your syntax error.

Your second syntax error comes from line 15:

```
var cloudPos_x:
```

It should end with a semicolon `;` not a colon `:`.

There are a lot of tools to check your syntax and it is usually a bad idea to code without one. [JSHint](https://jshint.com/) is one of them but it's not the only option, you should search for one which you can use easily with whatever IDE or text editor you are using to code.

Comment: Thank you. It solved 1 of the problems. However, I still receive the error no. 2 which is Error *sketch.js:23 Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token ':'* (colon), after I run the code.

Comment: @SuhailRafeeque Look at line 15: `var cloudPos_x:` it should be `var cloudPos_x;` you really should use a tool to validate your syntax like [jshint](https://jshint.com/) or any other one.

Comment: That solved the problem. Your contribution has been really valuable.

Comment: @SuhailRafeeque If the answer solved your problem you can mark it as accepted with the green tick on the left so that other users know that you found a satisfying answer and that will give you some reputation points. And if it helped you, you can also give it an upvote with the up arrow on the left which will also give me some points.

Comment: I could not find both the options you that mentioned. Could you share the screenshot or something because I have spent enough time to check these options.

Comment: You can read [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/288754) it's the etiquette on this site :)

Comment: I was looking at the wrong place. I have marked your answer green and voted it up. Appreciate it.